# SharePoint Webpart-Override a color from Bootstrap CDN

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, boot-strap

I have a webpart in SharePoint Online. I need to change the Text color of it. When I use the Firebug tool, it says that the location is https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css

```
body {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #333;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.42857;
}
```

I need to change the color to red. How do I achieve this?

Comment: just add your custom CSS `body { color: red; }`, if that doesn't work try `body { color: red !important; }`